# instantiating Form1 in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

When I create a new Windows Form Application, it generates the Program.cs file with this line in it:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

My question is how Form1 is instantiated as the proper form should be something like this:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

How can it work as the `Form1 myForm` part seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

The left-hand side of an object instantiation is just declaring a variable that will hold the instance. In the case you mentioned, there's no need to capture the object in a variable -- the newly-created reference is getting passed directly into `Application.Run`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the C# language works.

The `Form1 myForm` part is just creating a variable that you can use to reference an instance of the class.

The `new Form1();` part is the bit that creates the instance. And it is the instance that the `Application.Run()` function cares about.

---

Now, generally it is pointless creating an instance without a reference to it, as you won't be able to use it. But there are some exceptions. In this case, the instance is assigned to the parameter in the `Application.Run()` method. (so technically there is a reference to it)

For example:

```
public void Run(Form form)
{
    //can use form parameter here 
}

//inside some other function
Run(new Form1());
```

which is like doing:

```
Form form = new Form1();
```

The `Run()` method can then use that instance as it needs to.

---

Another example of not needing to keep a reference is a one-off method call, something like:

```
new Form1().DoSomething();
//here we no longer have access to the instance
```

But I tend to stay away from that stuff as it is rarely appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `Application.Run()`'s declaration probably looks something like this:

```
public void Run(Form formParameter)
{
   this._form = formParameter; 
   //lots of other stuff
}
```

So you see, the value of `new Form1()` will be assigned to `Run`'s `formParameter`.
Your intuition is partially correct but mislead. 
There are a good number of situations in which it is useful to instanciate / construct an object without assigning the object to a variable. Consider constructing an object and calling one of it's methods in one line `new Object().Method()`.